# Why does valgrind show "leak definitely lost" warning when returning a malloc'd pointer?

Tags: c, function-pointers, valgrind, void-pointers

I can't understand why there's a memory leak in this code.

I need to return a copy of the input value.

This is where valgrind shows the warning "8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1"

```
void* ADTGetIntValue(void* dato) {
int* val = malloc(sizeof(int));
memcpy(val, ((DataObject *)(dato))->valore, sizeof(int*));
return val;
}
```

That function is called by this through a function pointer:

```
void* adtGetValue(DataObject* dato){
    return (*dato->tipo->get_val)(dato);
}
```

in the main I printf the int and call the function: `*((int *) (adtGetValue(data)))`

This is the definition of the function pointer: `typedef void* (*ADTGetValue)(void*);` and these are the two structs used in the code

```
  typedef struct DataType
{
    ADTConstruct costruisci;
    ADTDestruct distruggi;
    ADTGetValue get_val;
    ADTSetValue set_val;
    ADTRandomValue rand_val;
    ADTReadFromKeyboard read_val;
    ADTWriteToMonitor stampa;
    ADTClone clona;
    ADTCompare compara;
} DataType;

typedef struct DataObject
{
    DataType* tipo;
    void* valore;
} DataObject;
```

Any advice is appreciated :)

Comment: Do you `free` the pointer returned by `adtGetValue`? If not, that's "definitely" a leak.

Comment: When you have a function that returns a pointer that you got from `malloc`, it becomes the responsibility of the code that calls that function to ensure that the pointer is passed to `free` at some point later, otherwise the allocated memory will leak.

Comment: How am I supposed to free it? I just call adtGetValue in the printf: `printf("\nCurrent value is: %d\n", *((int *) (adtGetValue(data))));`

Comment: you `memcpy` the wrong amount of bytes

Comment: You don't simply pass the result of calling the function to `printf()`.  You use something like: `int *free_me = adtGetValue(data); printf("Current value is: %d\n", *free_me); free(free_me);`.  You must capture the return value precisely so that you can free it and avoid a memory leak.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler still the same after adding this in the main `int* tmp = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *tmp = *((int *) (adtGetValue(data)));
  printf("\nHo generato casualmente il numero: %d\n", *tmp);
  free(tmp);`

Comment: That code is considerably more complex than what I wrote — unnecessarily complex — and it skips the crucial step of `free(*tmp)` which your rewrite requires.  You need _both_ `free(*tmp);` _and_ `free(tmp);` — in that order.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler now I understand, thank you.